# Ubuntu 12.04 Minecraft server hosting

Tags: server, windows, minecraft, ip

Can someone help me to understand how to host a Minecraft server through an IP?

I am connected to the internet through not one but two routers!

On Windows 7 I was used to using Hamachi. Is there an alternative (in Ubuntu) to Hamachi that doesn't request the program itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/) service.

From [FAQ](http://www.noip.com/support/faq/frequently-asked-questions/):

> Our Free Dynamic DNS service takes your Dynamic IP address and makes
>   it act as though it is static by pointing a static hostname to it and
>   checking every 5 minutes for changes to your IP address. If your IP
>   address changes, our Dynamic Update Client updates your hostname with
>   the current IP address. Which means you can run a server from home and
>   access your computer, or IP camera remotely.